Where is stored the order from WooCommerce product category terms?
I am trying to understand where the display order of product categories defined by the admin is stored in the database. I intend to use this field in an SQL query to retrieve and display product categories in the desired order. I have looked into the wp_terms table but I have not found the sorting field.
I thought it was menu_order or terms_order but neither seems to exist.

Thank you, it seems to work except that for some reason the last of the children of the parent categories is shown to me as first.

You can find WooCommerce product category order in wp_termmeta database table with meta_key = 'order' and value on meta_value column. It's linked to the related term via the term_id column.
